# is there a lower-graphics setting?

Tags: graphics, interface

Beginning Ubuntu user here.  I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit on an old Dell computer to replace Windows XP.  I like the interface, but I notice that it responds very slowly.  I suspect this is due to my older graphics card.  Is there a way I can disable some of the animation in the interface, or is there a version of Ubuntu that is less graphics-intensive?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering that the machine was running Windows XP previously, you are probably looking for a "lighter" flavour of Ubuntu. It is possible to disable some animations and effects from Unity/Gnome, but depending on how old is the PC, it might not be enough to make it usable.

[Xubuntu - XFCE Desktop Environment](http://xubuntu.org/)

[Lubuntu - LXDE Desktop Environment](http://lubuntu.net/)

The XFCE environment has a good compromise between usability, performance and customization, when compared to Unity/GNOME. LXDE is another good alternative, that is somewhat "lighter" than XFCE, but it also lacks some customization and usability when compared to the former.

Comment: He's looking for a way to run plain Ubuntu without using too many graphics card resources.